# Effect of many try-catch statements in fairly large client-side JavaScript single-page app

Tags: javascript, try-catch

In a fairly large single-page application in which a lot of JavaScript takes place on the client, is it inefficient to wrap all code of individual functions in try-catch statements?

I wrap the database requests in try-catch statements in the event that there is an error that takes place before a request is made, such that I can rollback the mapping data and other values that were incremented to be written to the database.  The rest of the code ought to always run without error but the user could tamper with the database values in a manner that could cause the code to fail.  I'd prefer to never have the program just terminate without at least giving the user some type of message before closing and preferably an option to salvage their work.

Does having so many try-catch statements have a negative impact in any area and is there a better way to accomplish the same?

Thank you.

Comment: No, having a good error handling strategy is never a bad thing. Of course, you should have the `try`/`catch` statements in the appropriate places, where you actually can *handle* an error - normally it's not that many.

Comment: Thank you.  If I do my part correctly, then the only errors should be due to someone tampering with the data, but even in that case I'd like to be able to display something of a fatal error message and disable all the buttons.